# python (boto3) program to delete old snapshots in aws by description

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So i am following this [guide](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/automated-ebs-snapshots-using-aws-lambda-cloudwatch) which is tremendously helpful for creating and deleting snapshots that are older than 3 days. the trouble is, it looks like the python script the author posted deletes all snapshots that are older than 10 days. Within my env, I have level 1's that sometimes create manual snapshots for various reasons, so i cant have this lambda function delete those and I want it to filter the snapshots by descriptions that have

`"Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots"`

Now, the author posted a way to filter snapshot created, so i attempted to mimic that by filtering descriptions for deletion, but I just want someone to check my work, and/or show me a better way, because what i have thus far is:

```
( Filters=[{'Description':['Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots']}])
```

**TLDR**: How do I add a filter in this code that only targets snapshots with said above description

This is the authors code for deletion:

```
# Delete snapshots older than retention period

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def delete_snapshot(snapshot_id, reg):
    print "Deleting snapshot %s " % (snapshot_id)
    try:  
        ec2resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=reg)
        snapshot = ec2resource.Snapshot(snapshot_id)
        snapshot.delete()
    except ClientError as e:
        print "Caught exception: %s" % e

    return

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get current timestamp in UTC
    now = datetime.now()

    # AWS Account ID    
    account_id = '1234567890'

    # Define retention period in days
    retention_days = 10

    # Create EC2 client
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

    # Get list of regions
    regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[] )

    # Iterate over regions
    for region in regions:
        print "Checking region %s " % region['RegionName']
        reg=region['RegionName']

        # Connect to region
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=reg)

        # Filtering by snapshot timestamp comparison is not supported
        # So we grab all snapshot id's
        result = ec2.describe_snapshots( OwnerIds=[account_id] Filters=[{'Description':['Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots']}])

        for snapshot in result['Snapshots']:
            print "Checking snapshot %s which was created on %s" % (snapshot['SnapshotId'],snapshot['StartTime'])

            # Remove timezone info from snapshot in order for comparison to work below
            snapshot_time = snapshot['StartTime'].replace(tzinfo=None)

            # Subtract snapshot time from now returns a timedelta 
            # Check if the timedelta is greater than retention days
            if (now - snapshot_time) > timedelta(retention_days):
                print "Snapshot is older than configured retention of %d days" % (retention_days)
                delete_snapshot(snapshot['SnapshotId'], reg)
            else:
                print "Snapshot is newer than configured retention of %d days so we keep it" % (retention_days)
```

The portion I updated was:
**result = ec2.describe_snapshots( OwnerIds=[account_id] Filters=[{'Description':['Created by Lambda backup function ebs-snapshots']}])**

is this correct syntactically?

Comment: Does it work? If so, I guess it is correct! Instead of using a filter, you could simply describe _ALL_ snapshots, and then use an additional `if` statement in Python to only delete snapshots that have the desired Description.